# Как удалить папку в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Для удаление файла применил 41H, но при указе `FILE DB 'D:\1'` (папка) она не удаляет, оно и ясно. Как это возможно сделать?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
FILE DB 'D:\1.txt',0
MSG DB 'File deleted','$'  ; Отображение успешного сообщения при удалении файла
.CODE
START: MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

;Часть удаление файла
LEA DX,FILE                ; Загрузка пути файла в DX
MOV AH,41H                 ; Удаление файла, AH=41H
INT 21H

;Часть вывода на экран              
JC EXIT                    
LEA DX,MSG                 ; Сообщение об успехе
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

;Завершение
EXIT:MOV AH,4CH            ; Завершаем программу
INT 21H
END START
```

Comment: Для удаления каталога используется fn=3Ah.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR1 DB 'D:\Papka1',0

.CODE    
;Часть удаление папки
LEA DX,DIR1                ; Загрузка пути папки в DX
MOV AH,3AH                 ; Удаление файла, AH=3AH
INT 21H
```